# Custom Header Content in Vuepress

Tags: vuepress

Wondering if there is an easy way to add custom header material for Vuepress docs.

In my current project, I'm using Turbolinks. When I visit the documentation written in Vuepress, Turbolinks maintains the same CSS from before (just reloads the body). All I need to do is to be able to add this:

`<meta name="turbolinks-visit-control" content="reload">`

to the head of each page.

Was hoping I could just add it to `config.js` like this:

`turbolinks-visit-control: reload`

but didn't work. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your config.js inside .vuepress folder and edit it to this

```
module.exports = {
      head: [
        ['meta ', { name: 'turbolinks-visit-control', content: 'reload' }]
      ]
}
```

You can visit [Vue Js Documentation Page](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#head) https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#head, for more information or details.